# Как что-то засунуть в map?

Tags: python, map

Подскажите.
Есть код

```
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x*y**5, map(int, input().split())))
```

Он возвращает произведение всех элементов в 5ой степени.
Но, проблема появилась вполне очевидная, если первый элемент НЕ 1, то считается криво.
Соответственно, костыль наше все.
Как добавить 1 первым элементом в map?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вопрос академический или практический? Вам важно решить это именно с использованием `reduce`? PS даже если первый элемент 1, то результат неверный

Comment: @MaxU
Вопрос академический.
Прохожу курсы на coursera и встрял с этим заданием.
Отчего же результат не верный?
Если поставить в начало 1, то все ответы сошлись.
Задание сейчас в вопрос скину.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:** в данном случае советую воспользоваться [соседним решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1101013/211923)

---

Если же у вас будет более сложный случай, то можно "разнести" операции по разным lambda функциям:

```
In [20]: reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, map(lambda x: int(x)**5, input().split()))
1 1 1 2
Out[20]: 32

In [21]: reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, map(lambda x: int(x)**5, input().split()))
2 1 1 2 2
Out[21]: 32768

In [22]: reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, map(lambda x: int(x)**5, input().split()))
10 100 1000 10000 2
Out[22]: 3200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

---

> как добавить что-то на первое и последнее место в map'e?

```
In [28]: reduce(lambda x, y: x*y**5, [1] + list(map(int, input().split())))
2 3
Out[28]: 7776

In [29]: reduce(lambda x, y: x*y**5, [1] + list(map(int, input().split())))
1 2 3
```

Comment: Да, это действительно проще вариант и рабочий.
Но, блин, как добавить что-то на первое и последнее место в map'e?

Comment: @BeerAndBear, а зачем добавлять? Все ведь правильно работает или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Нет, все верно)
Но, вдруг припрет нелегкая. Неплохо бы знать)

Comment: @BeerAndBear, если опять академический интерес, то я дополнил ответ (см. внизу ответа) :)

Answer (score 3):

Немного не по теме. Если нужно произведение элементов возвести в степень, то должно быть по-другому:

```
2*3**2 # как записано у вас, т.е. 3-ка возводится в степень 2-а, а затем домножается на 2-ку
# 18

(2*3)**2 # произведение возводится в степень, 2-ка перемножается на 3-ку и возводится во 2-ю степень
# 36
```

Comment: @MaxU, почему? Можно ведь всё перемножить, а потом возвести в степень

Comment: ++ ваше решение гораздо элегантнее: `reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, map(int, input().split())) ** 5`

Comment: @0xdb, в данном овете используется простой математический факт: `a^n * b^n == (a*b)^n` - это значительно упрощает использование `map(...)` :)

Answer (score 3):

Вот в соседних комментариях умные люди, но это как раз тот случай, когда знание стандартной библиотеки важнее ума.

В `map` вам не нужно ничего засовывать, потому что у `reduce` можно просто третьим аргументом указать значение, которое нужно использовать в качестве первого элемента.

```
print(reduce(lambda x, y: x*y**5, map(int, input().split()), 1))
                                              # Вот так вот ^^^
```

Кстати, если указывать этот третий аргумент, то `reduce` сможет корретно обрабатывать случаи, когда входная последовательность оказалась пустой. Поэтому указание этого аргумента во многих случаях позволяет обойтись без предварительных проверок на длину последовательности или конструкций `try ... except`

Comment: Хм. Спасибо. Также решение проблемы.

Но, вопрос остается открым. 
Условно, есть map, и в него нужно засунуть хоть что-то на 1,2 или nое место элемент. Как?)

Comment: @BeerAndBear, в сам map - никак, если не трогать код интерпретатора. В любом случае нужно работать либо с исходной последовательностью, либо обрабатывать уже результаты map.

Comment: неправильно выразился.
Да, вывод map'a ясен. Но, как мне вывести его же, + 1 элемент (первый, последний или n-ый)